# set content height 100% jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing jQuery Mobile page in which my CSS is

```
.ui-content {
  background: transparent url('./images/bg.jpg');
  background-size : 100% 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

but page displays like this

[image]

I don't want that empty space between content and footer 
content height till the footer

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445977/jquery-mobile-content-area-100-height-between-head-and-foot ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, Jaspers solution is outdated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Update

> I have added a [Pure CSS Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27617438/1771795) below.

I have noticed that `.ui-content` div doesn't fill the empty space 100%, it is still missing `2px`. Those comes from *fixed* toolbars *header* and *footer*, as they have `margin-top: -1px` and `margin-bottom: -1px` respectively. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zKS76/))

> [image]

It wasn't obvious before as both *page div* and *footer* have the same black `data-theme="b"`. I have changed `.ui-page`'s `background-color: red;` to show the difference.

Therefore, to achieve best results, it's necessary to check whether *toolbars* are fixed. Below is the *enhanced* solution.

### jQM >= 1.3

```
var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight()  - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();

var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();

/* content div has padding of 1em = 16px (32px top+bottom). This step
   can be skipped by subtracting 32px from content var directly. */
var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();

var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

$(".ui-content").height(content);
```

### jQM <= 1.2

Since *fixed* toolbars in jQuery Mobile 1.2 and below don't get `-1` for `top`/ `bottom`, there is no need to do subtract `1px` from toolbar's `.outerHeight()`.

```
var header = $(".ui-header").outerHeight();

var footer = $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kEtbL/)** - w/ fixed toolbars
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/69nER/)** - w/o fixed toolbars <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> On Desktop browser page will scroll by 1px; however, On mobile device it doesn't. It's caused by `body`'s height set to `99.9%` and `.ui-page` to `100%`.

Comment: great answer as usual! For completeness, I would add a scroll(0,0); before scaling, run it in the "pagecontainershow" event and also add handlers for window resize and orientationchange to keep the content sized (updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zKS76/4/ )

Comment: @ezanker thank you for sharing those important points, please add a separate comprehensive answer, for everybody's reference :)

Comment: OK, I added an answer for future reference.

Comment: Great find Omar!! We could make it more generic and actually add the TOP to the header and the BOTTOM to the footer (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kEtbL/2/). They are using absolute position and not negative margi. In this way if they decide to change to 2px instead of 1px or remove it in the future your code will still work. What do you think?

Comment: @ezanker good idea! If you check fixed header's css, you'll find `top: -1`.

Comment: Exactly, look at the fiddle in my last comment: parseInt($(".ui-header").css("top")) || 0; will find the -1 or return 0 if not fixed. parseInt($(".ui-footer").css("bottom")) || 0; does it for the footer...

Comment: @ezanker true, in case user overrides `.ui-header-fixed`'s `top` to any other negative value.

Comment: why getting footer height as null? My footer is <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-footer ui-bar-b ui-footer-fixed">

Comment: @user3059850 when are you retrieving footer's height?

Answer (score 15):

This is just to add a couple of points to @Omar's answer.

> His updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zKS76/4/)**

Put his scaling code inside a function and add scroll(0,0) to the top. This eliminates weird issues that can come up during orientation changes (portrait to landscape) on some devices.

```
function ScaleContentToDevice(){
    scroll(0, 0);
    var content = $.mobile.getScreenHeight() - $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").outerHeight() + $(".ui-content").height();
    $(".ui-content").height(content);
}
```

The function should then be called on pagecontainershow (pageshow if jQM 1.3) and you should add a handler for window resize and orientationchange to keep the content properly sized when the viewport size changes:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(){
    ScaleContentToDevice();        
});

$(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){
    ScaleContentToDevice();
});
```

Comment: Great solution! I oversaw the `orientationchange` event before. They should make this the default, or add a simple function to add this functionality, so we get it in a single line in jQM. It is just fundamental for responsive web design.

Comment: It took me a while to reproduce your result on JSFiddle. I finally hunted it down to the fact that you had your JS set to load in the body, and I had it `onLoad`. Very annoying. Is there a way to determine whether a page event has already fired (and if so, don't wait for it, but call the code instantly)?

Comment: @Domi, I don't really understand your question, but I guess you can set a global variable when a page event fires and then test for that variable...

Comment: I was looking for a built-in that already delivers such functionality, and I found it! [This updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/zKS76/19/) works, no matter when it is executed (in head, body or onload). It does so by checking whether `$.mobile.activePage` exists.

Comment: But this one not resizing the bg image

Comment: @AlokSInha, this is about resizing the content DIV, not any images you are using.

Answer (score 11):

### Pure CSS solution

> **Important note:** Use this solution for specific pages, where you don't want page or page's content to scroll vertically. Because page's `height` will set to `100%`, hence, it won't scroll and you will face this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055360/1771795).

1. **Full Screen:**

   ```css
   html,
   body,
   #pageID { /* specify page */
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   #pageID .ui-content {
     padding: 0;
   }

   .ui-content,
   .ui-content #full-height-div { /* divs will inherit page's height */
     height: inherit;
   }
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aLA4NyOEcSufWsKreGUD?p=info)**

---

2. **Fixed Toolbars (header/footer):**

   ```css
   html,
   body,
   #pageID {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   #pageID,
   #pageID * {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
             box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   #pageID .ui-content {
     height: inherit; /* inherit height without padding nor border */
   }
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQX76QS9DrPi8gKk5zTE?p=info)**

---

3. **Floating Toolbars:**

   ```css
   html,
   body,
   #pageID {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   #pageID,
   #pageID * {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
             box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   #pageID .ui-content {
     height: calc(100% - 89px); /* 88px = header's height 44px and footer's 44px plus 1px */
   }
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8eb8OqClS3ZMlM0wEFPQ?p=info)**

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve "height 100%" with CSS only. Add the following to your ui-content selector:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Tested on jQuery Mobile v1.4.3

Comment: @Kaganar If we remove data-position="fixed" from the header then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I change @ezanker 's answer.

It works, but if I have two pages, page 2 will resize when I go to page 2 from page 1.

And if I change event `pagecontainershow` to `pagecontainerbeforeshow`, it does not work correctly.

I debug and find height of header or footer is wrong before show.

**code**

```
function ScaleContentToDevice(nextPage){
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    var header = nextPage.children(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? nextPage.children(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : nextPage.children(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    var footer = nextPage.children(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? nextPage.children(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : nextPage.children(".ui-footer").outerHeight()
    var contentCurrent = nextPage.children(".ui-content").outerHeight() - nextPage.children(".ui-content").height();
    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;

    nextPage.children(".ui-content").height(content);
}

$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function(event, ui){
    var nextPage = $(ui.toPage[0]);
    ScaleContentToDevice(nextPage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS works fine for portrait pages. You must set top and bottom position depending of your header and footer height

```
position: absolute;
top: 88px; /*your header height*/
right: 0;
bottom: 44px; /*your footer height */
left: 0;
background: white;
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer isn't in resizing the content div but in changing the background color of the active page like this...

```
.ui-page-active {background: #f1f1f1; }
```

...to match the color of the ui-content and all of a sudden the problem goes away.

Answer (score -1):

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
```

will do it!