# failing to set div value height to fit the remaining space

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery and JQuery-Mobile to show a simple UI with a header and a map. I want the map to fit the whole screen, so its height is set to the height of the window minus the height of the header.

My javascript is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxWidth = $(window).width();
    var maxHeight = $(window).height();

    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    var heightMap = maxHeight - headerHeight;
    $('#map').css("height",heightMap);
```

The same lines are in the $(window).resize() function.

The map is well resized when the screen size changes, but the first time I load a page, in landscape, it's about 10 pixels heigher. How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't use `.ready()` in JQM, use page events. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile/21553307#21553307

Comment: Thanks, I solved by using $.mobile.getScreenHeight(); as I saw in your code! Now, I just have to fix the background size that is still bigger than the screen: I tried to resize the .ui-content and the body, but I still have a page bigger than screen size. Do you know what is the element that I have to modify?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Html code along with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
//your code in here
});
```

Comment: Adding to this, the reason is, `.ready` is called when the Dom is ready, `.load` is called when all contents are downloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not change anything