# jQM ui-content 100% height issue

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I follow this post trying to get my jQM Page ui-content background image height to 100%:
[Link to solution provided by Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile)

I got 2 problem, first is height doesn't meet 100% (short of 16px), second is the background image will stretch it's height a little longer before transition, and shrink back after transition. Anyone have any solution to fix this?

**The following is my code:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#userMainPage', function () {
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();
    alert("Screen height: " + screen);
    var header = $(".ui-header").hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
    alert("Header size: " + header);
    var footer = $(".ui-footer").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer").outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer").outerHeight();
    alert("Footer size: " + footer);
    /* content div has padding of 1em = 16px (32px top+bottom). This step can be skipped by subtracting 32px from content var directly. */
    var contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height();
    alert("ui-content outerHeight: " + $(".ui-content").outerHeight());
    alert("ui-content height: " + $(".ui-content").height());
    alert("ContentCurrent: " + contentCurrent);
    var content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    alert("Content: " + content);
    $(".ui-content").height(content);
});
```

I just can't get 100% height. My height is short of 16px to be Full 100% height.

**Following info for better debugging:**

- Screen height: 548
- header size: 44
- footer size: 34
- outerHeight: 32
- ui-content.height: 0
- contentCurrent: 32
- final new height: 438

Please tell me what is wrong here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My answer here explains how to set content div's height to fit screen 100% without causing page to scroll, in case contents are not filling viewport's height.

To apply this method on each and every page, you need to check for *active page* and then retrieve heights of header, footer and content div. You then need to apply the result on `.ui-content` within active page, and only on `pagecontainershow` or `pagecontainertransition`. Those events fire when page is fully shown, otherwise, you won't get actual height.

```
function contentHeight() {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"),
        screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
        header = $(".ui-header", activePage).hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight(),
        footer = $(".ui-footer", activePage).hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight(),
        contentCurrent = $(".ui-content", activePage).outerHeight() - $(".ui-content", activePage).height(),
        content = screen - header - footer - contentCurrent;
    /* apply result */
    $(".ui-content", activePage).height(content);
}

$(document).on("pagecontainertransition", contentHeight);
$(window).on("throttledresize orientationchange", contentHeight);
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FyTYs/)**

Comment: Ha haha ha haha I dared you :D

Comment: @Gajotres I'm just clarifying one of my answers (after-answer services) :P Maybe I should add that answer to the original answer.

Comment: Hi Omar, the height is now 100% but the page have vertical scroll even the page is empty. Any idea where is wrong?

Comment: @user3053891 it's difficult to know unless you provide more details. Do you have fixed toolbars? Are you calling the function on events as in my answer?

Comment: Ok I'll try make a simplified version to replicate the error on jsfiddle. Will update here again. Thank you.

Comment: @user3053891 sure, let me know once you create a fiddle :)