# jQuery Mobile orientation white space

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, whitespace, screen-orientation

I'm getting some whitespace when changing the orientation on any device. It looks like this:

[image]

I guess this is because jquery mobile sets the min-height of each page to the device-height, but only on init. So the height is still the old device height. I tried out to set it manually with css:

```
.ui-page {
  min-height: 10px !important;
}
```

And this sets the min-height on my Desktop correctly (I can't try it in landscape mode obviously) but it has no influence on my problem.

Does anyone know how to delete this area, so that the page ends with the image?

Comment: why not min-height: 100%?

Comment: I tried this out as well, it doesn't change anything. I'm not even sure if it is really a height issue.

Comment: Can you show abit more code, HTML eg

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile/  Omars answer gives you the calculation, my answer shows how to apply it on orientationchange, and adds the scroll(0, 0);