# How to make the header transparent and show underneath when it's hidden

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am toggling the header visibility and when I hide it, I need it to be transparent and show the scrolling content.

I tried several ways but the header is not transparent. Please note it's hidden correctly but it left a white background instead. So I wanted to make it transparent:

```
 $('.ui-header').hide().animate({opacity: 0.0});// Hide the header but its opacity doesn't get to 0
 $(".ui-header").css("backgroundColor", "transparent");// No effect
```

How to make the header transparent so it will show the content underneath?

Comment: If you hide it manually, you need to call `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()`. Page has top padding 40px for header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set content height 100% jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Are you sure that answer is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, kind of the same issue

Comment: I cant find any relevance; maybe I misunderstood your question. You may post an answer before this post gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-header").hide();
```

Should be sufficient. Hiding the element means not showing it, which is equivalent to setting the opacity of the element to zero.

When reading the [documentation for the jQuery function .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), it clearly states that `.hide()` without any parameters is the equivalent to `display: none;` in CSS.

If you can't find the error with JS, I suggest giving `display: none;` to the `ui-header` class in CSS. If neither works we need more code to track down the error and give you a proper answer.

Edit: A JSFiddle demo available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfou72og/1/).