# jQuery Mobile and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with jQuery Mobile and Google Maps. I have to create a mobile application with jQuery Mobile. 
My problem is that I can't display the map in the content, I see only grey space and browsers like Safari and Chrome can't see any type of errors or warnings. Firefox's console instead see a lot of warnings such as "unknown property "-moz-border-radius-topleft” Declaration Dropped.", "Error in parsing value for background-image. Declaration Dropped."

I loaded the code without jQueryMobile, like I did for a normal webpage, and it worked.

EDIT: What I can see, and to see what the console shows you can look here:

http://riccardocelli.altervista.org/temporaneo.php

I tried to change versions of jQuery and jQueryMobile but it doesn't work..

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pagemap", function () {
//here the google map is created and loaded 
...
...
Options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10000,
            maximumAge: 0,
            zoom:20
        };

...
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"), Options);
...
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pagemap" data-title="home">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div id="top">
        <a id="top1" href="index.php" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
        <a id="top2" href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map_container">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <div id="bottom">
            <a id="bottom1" href="#friends" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
            <a id="bottom2" href="Settings.php" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me?
All the errors are in the file: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css .

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to substitute "pagecreate" with "pageinit", "pageshow" but it doesn't work. I saw a lot of examples and demos but nothing of these worked in my mac.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You always have an option to edit the question than adding details in comments section. Also, can you please provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com example where it demonstrates the error that you're facing? Btw, did you check by setting a minimum height to the div `map_container`

Comment: Thank you @Ravimallya for your answer but the height don't change the result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the google map a starting point:

```
var myOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.231719,-113.030911),
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_container')[0], myOptions);
```

Also add a div within the jQM content div for your map container and set it's height.

## **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jrObVb)**

If you want the map to fill the available device height between header and footer, you can scale the content DIV according to this answer: [set content height 100% jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552308/set-content-height-100-jquery-mobile/21556605#21556605)

## **[DEMO2](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/ALBWrr)**